# how to insert data into same pouchdb with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, pouchdb

I have scenario that  first onload page i put data into one pouchdb and with same pouchdb with other event of click it have to go server and fetch data in same pouch but it create two id ,but i need is second time it have into same pouch with first time create id how can i do this??
out put:

```
first time:

ressss---->:{"rows":[{"value":{"existing":[{"pattano":1843,"surveyNo":"156   ","subdivNo":"3B","ownerDetails":[{"relNo":1,"ownerNo":1,"RelationCode":"3","status":"Existing","udsRatio":"0","MaxOwnNumb":"1","relation":"மகள்","owner":"த்ஃப்க்","surveyNo":"156   ","statofown":"E","relative":"த்ஃப்க்","subDivNo":"3B"}]}],"_id":"6163ED1A-B1E8-4A90-8EEF-BF4B1A1E6132","_rev":"1-dea5c55e64c7543a26f24192ec5e94a5"}}]}
```

second time:

```
ressss---->:{"rows":[{"value":{"existing":[{"pattano":1843,"surveyNo":"156   ","subdivNo":"3B","ownerDetails":[{"relNo":1,"ownerNo":1,"RelationCode":"3","status":"Existing","udsRatio":"0","MaxOwnNumb":"1","relation":"மகள்","owner":"த்ஃப்க்","surveyNo":"156   ","statofown":"E","relative":"த்ஃப்க்","subDivNo":"3B"}]}],"_id":"6163ED1A-B1E8-4A90-8EEF-BF4B1A1E6132","_rev":"1-dea5c55e64c7543a26f24192ec5e94a5"}},{"value":{"existing":[{"pattano":457,"surveyNo":"111","subdivNo":"4","ownerDetails":[{"relNo":2,"ownerNo":1,"RelationCode":"1","status":"Existing","udsRatio":"0","MaxOwnNumb":"4","relation":"மகன்","owner":"மணிவேல்","surveyNo":"111","statofown":"E","relative":"ஆலப்பன்","subDivNo":"4"}]}],"_id":"E421B84D-2481-4ED1-ABDD-0C0B24BAEB91","_rev":"4-6713d5be5336f69b0f6c776b5c343d49"}}]}
```

my function is:

```
function fetchOwners(existingOwnersObj)
    {
        //alert("in fetch owners");
        var inputVal = JSON.stringify(existingOwnersObj);
        //alert("inputVal===> "+inputVal);
        var hash1 = cal_hmac(inputVal);
        var m = "";
        document.getElementById('imgdiv')
            .style.display = 'block';
        $
            .ajax(
            {
                url: urlService + serviceName + '/getPattaOwnersforJoint?jsoncallback=?',
                headers:
                {
                    "emp_value": ses,
                    "signature": hash,
                    "roleId": roleId,
                    "timestamp": t,
                },
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: inputVal.toString(),
                // jsonpCallback:"aaa",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(data)
                {
                //  alert("im in success===>"+JSON.stringify(data));
                    existown = {};
                    existown.existing = data;
                    //existown.slNno=slNno++;
                    str = JSON.stringify(existown);
                     //alert("str----->"+str);
                    var str1 = JSON.parse(str);
                    //new Pouch('idb://tamilNilamExist', function(err, db)
                     Pouch(puch, function(err, db)
                    {
                        var doc = existown;
                        db.put(doc, function(err, doc)
                        {
                            if (err)
                            {
                                return console.error(err);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //alert("Data Locally Stored Successfully adkkdd exizthhh");
                                $("#imgdiv")
                                    .hide();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    // getexist(); 
                    // 
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, exception)
                {
                    // alert("Error:"+JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    alert("Error Occured");
                    document.getElementById('imgdiv')
                        .style.display = 'none';
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a very old version of PouchDB. If you update to 3.4.0, you should be able to easily do something like:

```
// only need to instantiate the PouchDB once
var db = new PouchDB('mydb');

// inside of asynchronous functions, just call the db directly
function asyncSomething() {
  function asyncSomethingElse() {
    db.put(...)
  }
}
```